# Kubuntu freezes after unplug-plug usb mouse

Tags: ubuntu, usb, mouse, freeze, kubuntu

Kubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa) freezes after unplug-plug usb mouse. I've tried a different mouse and different usb port but it didn't help.

These two strings from xorg logs look strange (logs after unplugging-plugging)

```
[    88.941] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    88.941] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

I don't think it's a hardware problem as on the same laptop I also have Windows 10 and everything works well with Windows.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. Have you tried different USB ports? (I am thinking of a hardware problem). You may want to [edit] your post to add this or other info...

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I tried. It didn't help. I don't think it's a hardware problem as on the same laptop I also have Windows 10 and everything works well with Windows.